# React native QRCode scanner integration problem

Tags: ios, react-native

im trying to integrate [react-native-qrcode-scanner](https://github.com/moaazsidat/react-native-qrcode-scanner) into my project. I do all they say in the installation guide but get following error :

[image]

I see that this line of code inside this library fails :

```
return PermissionsIOS.requestPermission(
```

**PermissionsIOS** being imported as

```
const PermissionsIOS = NativeModules.ReactNativePermissions
```

So it seems like permissions was not loaded into the project.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you run `react-native link react-native-permissions`?

Comment: yepp, it what it says in the guide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found it. The thing is that by some strange reason `react-native link react-native-permissions` didnt work out. I've read installation on [react-native-permissions](https://github.com/yonahforst/react-native-permissions)'s page. It says that one of 3 following  must be done :

1. Installation via pods - **made only worse**
2. running `react-native link react-native-permissions` - **didnt work in first place**
3. Manual linkage with XCode

Only 3rd alternative did the trick for me.